# Spring integration DSL example of file polling inbound channel adapter

Tags: spring-integration, spring-dsl

Can't find an example anywhere using spring integration DSL only xml. Any pointers appreciated, also need the poller to trigger on file creation and modification

Answer (score 2):

How bout this one:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(s -> s.file(tmpDir.getRoot()).patternFilter("*.sitest"),
                    e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(100)))
            .transform(Transformers.fileToString())
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("fileReadingResultChannel"))
            .get();
}
```

?
The `.from()` factory method accepts here a `MessageSources` factory, from where you are using `.file()` factory method and so on.

More information is in the projects tests: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test

Comment: Thanks Artem but will this poller trigger on file creation / modification? My orig. sol. was using the Java nio lib to achieve this.